# how to add selectoption to the view select discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have code like this

```
class RolePickView(discord.ui.View):
def __init__(self):
    super(RolePickView, self).__init__(timeout=None)
    self.select_max_values = 1  # default value
    self.author_id = None
    self.select_options = {}

@discord.ui.select(placeholder='Выберите роль...', custom_id='rolepick-select')
async def select_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
    user = interaction.user
    for role_id in select.values:
        role = interaction.message.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
        await user.add_roles(role)
    await interaction.response.send_message("Роли выданы", ephemeral=True)
```

Tell me please, how can I dynamically add SelectOption to this select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically add options to the select it might be better to construct it using a class instead of a decorator and a function (You would add it manually to the View).

I would suggest either passing a list of `SelectOption`s or using the `add_option` method.

You can find more information here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=select#discord.ui.Select.add_option